# iphone -- switching between game center sandbox and production environments

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, game-center

I am having a terrible time with this.  Either my device is in sandbox mode and I want it to be in production mode, or vice versa.  I typically go into the settings app and sign myself out of the app store.  I seem to remember reading in a doc somewhere that this would allow me to switch.  But I still generally can't switch to whichever environment I need to be in.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to sign yourself out from the account button of the GameCenter app.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  You have to sign-out in the Game Center App, but the button is hard to find since it's just a yellow rectangle that has your Game Center name on it.  You then HAVE TO sign into your sandbox account from within your App.  You can not sign into the Sandbox account via the Game Center App (despite it appearing that you have).

Comment: _“You can not sign into the Sandbox account via the Game Center App”_  Unfortunately, in iOS 7 this is no longer the case: [Screenshot of iOS 7.1.2 Game Center Sandbox Login](http://cl.ly/X1ez)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7.1 it took me awhile to figure it out but the way to sign out is: go to Settings -> Game Center -> click your Apple ID email. Three options show up in a popup. Hit sign out. Such a bad UI design.